# Маршалинг .net string[] как char**

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

На данный момент я маршалирую массив строк так:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
```

Правильно ли так делать? Это понятно что массив указателей, и массив символов, но я в недоразумении немного от маршалинга.

Comment: Так проверьте в C++ коде, все ли ок. + вам нужно передать длину массива отдельным параметром. Внешний код никак не сможет это определить по одному только указателю.

Comment: @Zergatul: Внешнему коду передается размер массива строк, но не длина массива символов, проблем же не должно быть?

Comment: Массив символов заканчивается нулем, все должно быть ок